# How to use different templates for InDesign XML import

Tags: xml, adobe-indesign

I am trying to import XML data to InDesign and I have no problem with single template using tags but I would like to add attribute to `<PAGE>` node with template name or url to use during import.

Is using different template for each node even possible?

This is simple XML data which I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<PAGES>
 <PAGE>
    <NAME>DIAG-1</NAME>
    <Image href="file:///images/DIAG-1.jpg"/>
    <FOOTNOTE>TEXT 1</FOOTNOTE>
 </PAGE>
 <PAGE>
    <NAME>DIAG-2</NAME>
    <Image href="file:///images/DIAG-2.jpg"/>
    <FOOTNOTE>TEXT 2</FOOTNOTE>
 </PAGE>
 <PAGE>
    <NAME>DIAG-3</NAME>
    <Image href="file:///images/DIAG-3.jpg"/>
    <FOOTNOTE>TEXT 3</FOOTNOTE>
 </PAGE>
</PAGES>
```

Comment: Add different attributes to your PAGE tag and process them with ExtendScript after import

Comment: @NicolaiKant I am new at scripting in InDesign so maybe you have example of this approach?

Comment: I do not not have something ready made, but scripting manual would have a few relevant examples: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/indesign/sdk/cs6/scripting/InDesign_ScriptingGuide_JS.pdf. this has a chapter on dealing with XML and XMLElements